# how to roll back multiple @transactional methods when one of them is not committed or has exception in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Suppose we have some `@Transactional` methods and we want to rollback all methods if one or more of them has not committed successfully.is there any direct way in spring framework?

I tried rollbackfor attribute in one `@Transactional` method to rollback if one exception happened but I want it for multiple methods to happen

Comment: Simply run all of them in one transaction. I believe Spring allows you to just make one `@Transactional` method that would call all of them (and they would use the same transaction).

Comment: Even if all of the methods have `@Transactional` it'll just join the existing transaction. You need `TransactionPropagation.REQUIRES_NEW` to have new transactions created even if there's an existing in progress. Sorry, that's what Jorn said, but here are the details.